# Getting CheckBox checked state in a Python FMX GUI app

Tags: python, user-interface, checkbox, firemonkey

I've created a small app in the [DelphiFMX GUI library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python) that has a `Checkbox`, `Button`, and `Label` on it:

[image: Python GUI form with checkbox, button and label]

When I click on the button, then I simply want to check the checked state of the checkbox and then write into the label whether it is checked or not. I have the following code currently for clicking on the button, but it doesn't work:

```
def Button_OnClick(self, sender):
    if self.myCheckBox.Checked:
        self.myLabel.Text = "The Checkbox is Checked"
    else:
        self.myLabel.Text = "The Checkbox is Unchecked"
```

When I click on the button, then I get the following run-time error
`AttributeError: Error in getting property "Checked". Error: Unknown attribute`:

[image: AttributeError: Error in getting property "Checked". Error: Unknown attribute]

What is the correct or best way to get the `Checked` state of a `CheckBox` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `isChecked` property:

```
def Button_OnClick(self, sender):
    if self.myCheckBox.isChecked:
        self.myLabel.Text = "The Checkbox is Checked"
    else:
        self.myLabel.Text = "The Checkbox is Unchecked"
```